# HTML icon inside md-tab md-on-select label with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-material, material-design

I have code using the following angularjs material functionality:

```
<md-tab md-on-select="something" label="{{subsetKey}} ({{subset.data ? subset.data.length : 0;}}) <i class='example icon class'></i>" ng-repeat="(subsetKey, subset) in dogBreeds[(dog === 0 ? 'All' : dog.BreedID)].subsetList">
```

I need to add an icon with this label, but it renders as text rather than the icon like:

```
<md-tab-item>
     Labrador <i class='example icon class'></i>
</md-tab-item>
```

Please note, this doesn't use the structure found in the AngularJS demo below
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

```
<md-tab id="something">
    <md-tab-label>something label</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>something body</md-tab-body>
</md-tab>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so basically you want to set the icon class dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code to something like this:

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab md-on-select="something" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <md-tab-label>
            Labrador
            <i class='example icon class'></i>
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
            {{item}}
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

I do not know how much you need to have your code like it is right now, but changing it to something more structured would be easier for you as you can also add all the info you need!!